# Acesso a variaveis em outra classe

Tags: java

Tenho que fazer um projeto para a faculdade e nele tenho um menu de configurações, o qual está em uma classe separada da principal, porém quando tento "salvar" tais configurações a classe principal não enxerga a mudança e fica com o valor original. Tentei fazer com Gets e Sets.

Fiz um exemplo para tentar explicar

Essa é a primeira classe no inte é uma variável do tipo inteiro e global

```
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inte);
      setInte(10);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inte);
      new dois().setVisible(true);
```

E a aqui a segunda classe onde tento capturar o valor

```
    um teste = new um ();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, teste.getInte());
```

Na saída da segunda classe ele saí como 0.

Alguma sugestão? 
Obrigado!

Comment: O que vem a ser a sua classe `um` e `dois`, que aliás são classes com péssimos nomes? Como é o código do seu `setInte`? Como você declarou `inte`?

Comment: Como disse são apenas exemplos, por isso estão com esses nomes.    

    public int inte;

Comment: Ou seja, se você usou `public int inte`, então não era variável global. Para ser uma variável global, ele teria que ser `public static int inte`. Além disso, variáveis globais não são boas práticas de programação, ainda mais se públicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São dois objetos diferentes. 
Na primeira classe você tem um objeto onde seta o valor.
Na segunda classe ao fazer  `um teste = new um ();` você está criando um novo objeto na memória, você não está acessando o objeto anterior. 
O que você pode fazer é utilizar um design pattern chamado **Singleton** ( Onde voce retorna a mesma instancia do objeto)

Por exemplo:

```
  public class Classe1 {
    Classe1 instancia;
    public static Classe1 getInstancia(){
        return instancia;
    }
  }

  public class Classe2 {
     Classe1 = Classe1.getInstancia();
  }
```